# (ASK) Failed on adding and updating data to database mysqli using codeIgniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, mysqli

So I tried to make a simple crud application. It works well when I try to delete,otherwise it always goes wrong when it comes to adding and updating data. My script didnt succeed on adding or updating data to the database. I'm using code igniter php frameworks here

Here are my script of controller and models for your references

```
    <?php
    //script of controller
    class Siswa extends CI_Controller
    {
      private $limit=10;

      function __construct()
      {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library(array('table','form_validation'));
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
        $this->load->model('siswa_model','',TRUE);
      }

      function index($offset=0,$order_column='id',$order_type='asc')
      {
        if(empty($offset))
            $offset=0;

        if(empty($order_column))
            $order_column='id';

        if(empty($order_type))
            $order_type='asc';

        $siswas=$this->siswa_model->get_paged_list($this->limit,$offset,$order_column,$order_type)->result();

        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = site_url('siswa/index');
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->siswa_model->count_all();
        $config['per_page']=$this->limit;
        $config['url_segment']=3;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['pagination']=$this->pagination->create_links();

        $this->load->library('table');
        $this->table->set_empty("&nbsp;");
        $new_order=($order_type=='asc'?'desc':'asc');
        $this->table->set_heading
        (
            'No',
            anchor('siswa/index/'.$offset.'/nama'.$new_order,'Nama'),
            anchor('siswa/index/'.$offset.'/alamat'.$new_order,'Alamat'),
            anchor('siswa/index'.$offset.'/jenis_kelamin'.$new_order,'Jenis Kelamin'),
            anchor('siswa/index'.$offset.'/tanggal_lahir'.$new_order,'Tanggal Lahir (dd-mm-yyyy)'),
            'Actions'
        );
        $i=0+$offset;
        foreach ($siswas as $siswa)
        {
            $this->table->add_row(++$i,
                $siswa->nama,
                $siswa->alamat,
                strtoupper($siswa->jenis_kelamin)=='M'?
                'Laki-laki':'Perempuan',
                date('d-m-Y',strtotime(
                    $siswa->tanggal_lahir)),
                anchor('siswa/view/'.$siswa->id,
                    'view',array('class'=>'view')).' '.
                anchor('siswa/update/'.$siswa->id,
                    'update',array('class'=>'update')).' '.
                anchor('siswa/delete/'.$siswa->id,
                    'delete',array('class'=>'delete',
                        'onclick'=>"return confirm
                        ('Apakah Anda yakin ingin menghapus data siswa?')"))
                );
        }

        $data['table']=$this->table->generate();

        if($this->uri->segment(3)=='delete_success')
            $data['message']='Data berhasil dihapus';

        else if ($this->uri->segment(3)=='add_succsess')
            $data['message']='Data berhasil ditambah';

        else
            $data['message']='';

        $this->load->view('siswaList',$data);
    }

    function add()
    {
        $data['title']='Tambah siswa baru';
        $data['action']= site_url('siswa/add');
        $data['link_back'] = anchor('siswa/index/','Back to list of siswas',array('class'=>'back'));

        $this->_set_rules();
        if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        {
            $data['message']='';
            $data['title']='Add new siswa';
            $data['message'] = '';
            $data['siswa']['id']='';
            $data['siswa']['nama']='';
            $data['siswa']['alamat']='';
            $data['siswa']['jenis_kelamin']='';
            $data['siswa']['tanggal_lahir']='';
            $data['link_back'] = anchor('siswa/index','Lihat Daftar Siswa',array('class'=>'back'));

            $this->load->view('siswaEdit',$data);
        }

        else
        {
            $siswa = array('nama'=>$this->input->post('nama'),
                'alamat'=>$this->input->post('alamat'),
                'jenis_kelamin'=>$this->input->post('jenis_kelamin'),
                'tanggal_lahir'=>date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('tanggal_lahir'))));

            $this->validation->id = $id;
            $data['siswa']=$this->siswa_model->add($id,$siswa);
            redirect('siswa/index/add_success');
        }   

    }

    function view($id)
    {
        $data['title']='siswa Details';
        $data['link_back']= anchor('siswa/index/','Lihat daftar siswas',array('class'=>'back'));

        $data['siswa']=$this->siswa_model->get_by_id($id)->row();

        $this->load->view('siswaView',$data);
    }

    function update($id)
    {
        $data['title']='Update siswa';
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->_set_rules();
        $data['action']=('siswa/update/'.$id);

        if($this->form_validation->run()===FALSE)
        {
            $data['message']='';
            $data['siswa']=$this->siswa_model->get_by_id($id)->row_array();
            $_POST['jenis_kelamin'] = strtoupper($data['siswa']['jenis_kelamin']);
            $data['siswa']['tanggal_lahir']=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($data['siswa']['tanggal_lahir']));   

            $data['title']='Update siswa';
            $data['message']='';    
        }

        else
        {
            $id=$this->input->post('id');
            $siswa=array('nama'=>$this->input->post('nama'),
                'alamat'=>$this->input->post('alamat'),
                'jenis_kelamin'=>$this->input->post('jenis_kelamin'),
                'tanggal_lahir'=> date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('tanggal_lahir'))));

            $this->siswa_model->update($id,$siswa);

            $data['message']='update siswa success';
        }

        $data['link_back']= anchor('siswa/index/','Lihat daftar siswas',array('class'=>'back'));

        $this->load->view('siswaEdit',$data);
    }

    function delete($id)
    {
        $this->siswa_model->delete($id);
        redirect('siswa/index/delete_success','refresh');

    }       

    function _set_rules()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama','Nama','required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('jenis_kelamin','Jenis Kelamin','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('alamat','Alamat','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('tanggal_lahir','Tanggal Lahir','required|callback_valid_date');
    }

    function valid_date($str)
    {
        if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$/',$str))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_date','date format is not valid. dd-mm-yyyy');
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

}

?>
```

---

```
<?php
//script of model
class Siswa_model extends CI_Model
{
    private $primary_key='id';
    private $table_name='siswa';

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function get_paged_list($limit=10,$offset=0,$order_column='',$order_type='asc')
    {
        if(empty($order_column) || empty ($order_type))
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->primary_key,'asc');
        }

        else
        {
            $this->db->order_by($order_column,$order_type);
        }

        return $this->db->get($this->table_name,$limit,$offset);
    }

    function count_all()
    {
        return $this->db->count_all($this->table_name);
    }

    function get_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->where($this->primary_key,$id);
        return $this->db->get($this->table_name);
    }

    function save($person)
    {
        $this->db->insert($this->table_name,$person);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    function update($id,$person)
    {
        $this->db->where($this->primary_key,$id);
        $this->db->update($this->table_name,$person);
    }

    function delete($id)
    {
        $this->db->where($this->primary_key,$id);
        $this->db->delete($this->table_name);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function add() {
...........
$siswa = array('nama'=>$this->input->post('nama'),
            'alamat'=>$this->input->post('alamat'),
            'jenis_kelamin'=>$this->input->post('jenis_kelamin'),
            'tanggal_lahir'=>date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('tanggal_lahir'))));

        $this->validation->id = $id;
        $data['siswa']=$this->siswa_model->add($id,$siswa);
        redirect('siswa/index/add_success');
```

$id is not declared anywhere.

You call $this->siswa_model->add($id,$siswa) but the function add() does not exists in siswa_model (it's called save())

Comment: I did. Thanks to you now the adding process works. But it still doesnt work on update

Comment: Siswa_model:     update($id,$person)

Can you var_dump($person) so we know for sure there is some data submitted?
And also do $this->db->last_query(); after you run the db->update() so we can check what query is generated.